# How do you get Dog Fight medals?

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

I'm working on unlocking the various camos and one of the challenges is to get 50 Dog Fight medals. How are these earned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Killing someone while both of you are in the air. Use the hover exo ability to make it easier

Comment: Note: Falling off a tall structure doesn't count as you, or them, being in the air. Both must use an exo boost / hover to be in the air.

Answer (score -1):

Basically exo jumping into the air as you would to get a strafe medal only this time your enemy has to be in the air too. Kill them then at the top of your screen will appear the strafe medal. GOOD LUCK!

Answer (score -2):

To get the Dog Fight medal, you simply have to be in the air during the kill as well.